# add a tag inside div using greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

There is a website where a div looks like this

```
<div class="xyz">
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in/search?q=joker" target="abc">google</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/search?q=joker" target="abc">youtube</a>
</div>
```

i want to insert

```
<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=joker">duckduckgo</a>
```

like this

```
<div class="xyz">
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in/search?q=joker" target="abc">google</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/search?q=joker" target="abc">youtube</a>
    <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=joker">duckduckgo</a>
</div>
```

using anything like javascript in greasemonkey or tampermonkey
please help me out
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

All that is needed is to find on page such element and then add new line:

```
var my_div = document.getElementsByClassName("xyz"); 
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + '<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=joker">duckduckgo</a>';
```